# grabing selectedtext from textbox fails and is skipped

Tags: c#, winforms

im attempting to have a double, contain the selectedtext of a textbox. then it is doing this equation

```
double1 = double.Parse(textBox1.SelectedText);
            double2 = double.Parse(string1);
            double3 = double.Parse(string2);
            double4 = double2 * Math.Pow((double1 / double3), 2.333);
            textBox5.Text = double4.ToString();
```

setting breaks in my code, at each piece, it hits the first line the

```
double1 = double.Parse(textBox1.SelectedText);
```

it highlights the line,  i hit F11 to continue, and it skips all of the rest of the code after.

Comment: What did you mean with, it fail?

Comment: as in i have code after it that i use double1 in, but skips all of that code and continues on.

Comment: What error are you getting? Is is possible that the number has a comma as a decimal separator? Does it fail with integer numbers? Does `SelectedText` have the text you want to parse?

Comment: Might help to see some more of the code that is around this

Comment: that statement with just that code is impossible.  Can you post the code around it?

Comment: Seems like it is throwing an error from being unable to parse the text. Using the TryParse like in the answer from @BendEg shoulds stop this, though I imagine you'll just end up getting 0 as something will be wrong with your input. When you are debugging, what value does textBox1.SelectedText have?

Comment: its showing that the selectedText is grabbing the user input. so example i put 1000 in the textbox and it showed that the value was 1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with user-inputs, always catch wrong inputs. I would use:

```
double yourValue = 0;

if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out yourValue))
{
    // here you can process with the correct value
}
else
{
    // Here you can inform the user about a wrong input.
}
```

I forget to tell you, that your Thread-Culture is important for parsing double-values, because it decides whether a point or a comma devide the decimal numbers.

Comment: so i put my code into this, and its failing to put the selected text into the double, its showing that the selected text is 1000 (which is what i had entered on the front) it then goes straight to my else (messagebox.show("fail")) and continues.

Comment: the issue was that selectedtext wasnt grabbing anything, by changing it to simply textbox1.text, out double1 it continued with my code and worked.